# Store input value into database

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I'm trying to make a quantity box for my shopping cart but don't know how to store the value in my database.

```
<?php 
     $db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'store');
     $select_product = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM cart WHERE id = 0");
     $select_product_values = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_product);
     $product_quantity = select_product_values['quantity'];

     echo "<input type='text' maxlength='2' name='quantity' value=".$product_quantity." class='quantity_box'/>";
     echo "<form action='checkout.php' method='post'><button type='submit' id='checkout'>Checkout</button></form>";
     mysqli_close($db);
?>
```

What would be the simplest way to `update` the `value` of `quantity` on checkout?

Comment: Are you talking about how to frame an `UPDATE` statement on the back-end database or how to get this quantity value from this HTML textbox?

Comment: I'm talking about getting the quantity value of this HTML textbox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Update -

To grab the quantity, you would do this: (Fixed HTML):

```
 echo '
    <form action='checkout.php' method='post'>
        <input type="text" maxlength="2" name="quantity" value="'.$product_quantity.'" class="quantity_box"/>
        <button type="submit" id="checkout">Checkout</button>
    </form>';
```

Check the value sent from the form:

```
if(isset($_POST['quantity']) && !empty($_POST['quantity'])){
    $quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
    $updateCartSQL = "Update yourTable set quantity = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($quantity) . "'";
}
```

---

## Important!

**Make sure you clean any user input before inserting the data into the database. Better yet, check out [mysqli prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) to be extra secure!**

Comment: Yes but, how do i grab the value of my input box with the name of quantity?

Comment: @Dany : It would be available as a POST request parameter on the server. @Evan the `UPDATE` statement you wrote is dangerous.

Comment: @Lion I realize that and I informed the OP that it was so.

Comment: Oh yeah, $_POST, obviously. I'm not used to the way PHP works yet.